# VideoDisplay and black on top and bottom

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, mxml

i'm using videodisplay to play a rtmp stream, streamed video is 800X600 which also the size of the videodisplay.
but when it starts to play a black area appears on both top and bottom of the video.

attached image shows what i mean

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that those black stripes are not a part of the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the ratio of video, but I think you can use something like this:

```
videoDisplay.scaleMode = ScaleMode.STRETCH;
```

or

```
videoDisplay.scaleMode = ScaleMode.LETTERBOX;
```

---

**Update :**

So in this case I think setting `maintainAspectRatio` as *false* within your `<mx:videoDisplay />` will help you, Although the main purpose of that is maintaining the original aspect ratio while resizing the video.

Comment: hello, i'm using the <mx tag, my job is to improve that application built on flex 3 which doesn't support spark.

Comment: Then in this case, you can use `maintainAspectRatio`. I updated my answer